# How to not reload iFrame between page clicks

Tags: asp.net, ajax, iframe, sitecore, sitecore6

I'm having a tough nut to crack here. 
I have the following situation:
- in an iFrame (no way around it) I'm loading an external website/application.
- This iFrame is on one page and one page only.
- Whenever you visit the iFrame page the first time a certain load time is needed for the applicaton (about 5seconds on average).
- In the application you can change the view and parameters etc.
- When you leave that page and go to another, and return later on to the iFrame page the requirement is that there is no load, and the content of the iFrame is as you have left it earlier.

I know this can be done by using frames (which are so 90's) but I really don't want to do that. There has to be a more modern way of doing it.

Just to note, the website around the iFrame is using Sitecore, so this might be a limiting factor in some solutions.

The things I have thought of:
- use 2 frames, one for the header with navigation, and another for the content. In that way the iframe never has to reload and we have moved back in time... :(
- ever click is an Ajax call, the iFrame is in a div that is hidden until the right button is clicked.

And then I found something called BigPipe. I haven't found an ASP.NET implementation yet, but I was hoping someone already had some experience with this.

Anyone any better ideas?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

If your iFrame is a control on a Sitecore sublayout or rendering (or can be moved to a rendering/sublyaout), you can check off the Cacheable option on the sublayout and set it to vary by content or device or whatever depending on what it is.  Then you will have the content of that frame in Sitecore's cache, which is managed by Sitecore and it'll always render the cached version whenever possible and should basically solve your dilemma.